# Xero integration with Rails/Devise Omniauthable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm wanting to use devise's omniauthable to authenticate my user's accounting credentials in order to utilize Xero's api. But when I try to authorize with this gem, I get 400 Bad Request, Oauth::Unauthorized.
I have registered the application on Xero's site, and generated the API keys (CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET).

Here are the relevant routes:

```
 scope module: :user do
        devise_for :accounting_credentials,
                   path: :accounting,
                   controllers: {
                     omniauth_callbacks: 'application/users/accounting_credentials/omniauth_callbacks'
                   }
    end
```

My controller

```
class Application::Users::AccountingCredentials::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def xero
    ...
  end
```

Devise initializer
`config.omniauth :xero, ENV['CONSUMER_KEY'], ENV['CONSUMER_SECRET']`

and the model

```
class AccountingCredential < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i[xero]
  ...
end
```

I have my debugger at the start of Application::Users::AccountingCredentials#xero to see the information coming in. But I am unable to even get there as I get the above error first.  I've never really had any issues user Devise and Omniauth. I could make my own client to authorize with Xero, but figured this would be the cleaner/quicker approach.

Answer (score 0):

This always happens. I post a question after searching for a few hours, continue to search for answers, and then find the answer I need. Xero requires a callback domain that they ***claim*** is optional. It is not. I had to use ngrok to allow for the https that Xero requires. and then use that url for the apps url and then the domain in the callback. In my case it was `https://[number].ngrok.io` and the callback domain: `[number].ngrok.io`